# How i want make 3 rows of the same primary key into 1 row by checking and choose its value using case

Tags: sql, oracle, concatenation, case

For example here, from this table

```
key  | status
1001 |   A
1001 |   D
1001 |   C
```

the hierarchy will be C>D>A

If the the stats contain C as the value, the person status will become C in one row. It will be like this:

```
key  | status
1001 |   C
```

it will ignore D and A because it has value C. If it doesn't has C,then it will check for D first before A.
So, how can i do that? I dont how to make the 3 row into 1. I tried using

```
''' CASE WHEN STATUS IN('C')THEN 'C'
         ELSE WHEN STATUS IN('D') THEN 'D'
         ELSE WHEN STATUS IN('A') THEN 'A'
    END AS STATUS '''
```

But it give error and still can't make the row into 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below -

```
select key, status
from tablname
order by case when status='C' then 1 when status='D' then 2 when status='A' then 3 else 99 end 
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use analytical function `row_number` as follows:

```
Select * from
(Select t.*, 
       Row_number() over (partition by key order by case when status = 'C' then 1 
                                when status = 'D' then 2
                                when status = 'A' then 3 end) as rn
  From your_table)
Where rn = 1;
```